# Android Jenkins: ERROR: A snapshot operation is pending and timeout has expired

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use `android-emulator` plugin for jenkins to run my instrumentation tests.

At first, I tried to create an avd on the go, but was continuously facing some problems. So, I created the avd manually using the `avdmanager` tool and now I am using `Run existing emulator` option.

It's able to detect the emulator but still not able to launch it successfully. 
Here's the stacktrace:

```
[android] Starting Android emulator
[android] Erasing existing emulator data...
$ /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk//emulator/emulator -ports 5780,5781 -report-console tcp:5820,max=60 -avd test -wipe-data -no-window -verbose
emulator: Android emulator version 27.1.12.0 (build_id 4623001) (CL:c1ee4b7cb9d5d2ffedb862a09592bfa451551d6c)
emulator: Found AVD name 'test'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/system.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/vendor.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/userdata-qemu.img failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/userdata.img failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/userdata.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/cache.img failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/cache.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/version_num.cache failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/encryptionkey.img failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/hardware-qemu.ini failed
emulator: Deleting file /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/emulator-user.ini failed
emulator: Failed to remove snapshot directory '/var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/snapshots'
emulator: argv[0]: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk//emulator/emulator'; program directory: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/

emulator: Probing for /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu: file exists
emulator: Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
emulator:  Found directory: /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/

emulator: emuDirName: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/

emulator: Probing for /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu-64: file missing
emulator: try dir /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator: Adding library search path: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Running :/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-ports"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "5780,5781"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-report-console"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[04] = "tcp:5820,max=60"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[05] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[06] = "test"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[07] = "-wipe-data"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[08] = "-no-window"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[09] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /var/lib/jenkins/.emulator: Android virtual device file at: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: using snapshot lock path: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/snapshot.lock
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 23
emulator: Read property file at /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: (null)
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86//system.img
emulator: No vendor image
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/test.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
emulator: VM heap size 0MB is below hardware specified minimum of 256MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 10.1.5.1
emulator: ERROR: A snapshot operation for 'test' is pending and timeout has expired. Exiting...

[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ /var/lib/jenkins/.android-sdk//platform-tools/adb kill-server
```

As you can see, this is the error:

`ERROR: A snapshot operation for 'test' is pending and timeout has expired. Exiting...`

I am not sure how do I fix this. When did it start this 'snapshot opearion'? I've tried with both enabling/disabling `Use emulator snapshots` option.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the current user has no rights for the folder the emulator was in.

(I copied the emulator from one to another OS-User)